# How can I get a copy of my UK refusal letter?

Tags: uk, paperwork

Please how can I get a copy of my UK refusal letter ?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a Subject Access Request https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration online or by email. You’ll need to provide evidence to confirm your identity.

You can ask for Basic, Specific, or Detailed information, depending on what you need.  You should clearly describe what documents you need, for example a particular decision letter.

Comment: It was asking for UK postcode and i live in Nigeria

Comment: Did you email the contact given on the web page?

Comment: Have done that and i am waiting for there response

Comment: Is the samething, asking for uk address

Comment: That seems strange. Do you want a copy because you are applying for another visa? If so, typically applicants who don’t have full details of a refusal can just declare any previous denials in the new application and provide as much detail as they can remember eg the visa type and approximate date of refusal.